# Rails external API - best practices

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, conventions

## Prologue

I’ve recently decided to pick up Rails, this happened after a newly discovered infatuation with Ruby, I'm practically scratching the surface.

I, as most developers (experienced or otherwise) trying to pick up rails, have discovered how greatly it relies on [COC(convention over configuration)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration), having said that, I'm finding it increasingly difficult to find answers the more specific my questions get so thought I might ask the community :)

Even after visiting the second page of the google search results.

## Problem

I'm building a web app that relies heavily on an external API, and I'm not quite sure how to deal with activerecord (since I don't think I'll be using is), but I do need to use sessions.
What is the Rails best practice in this situation?

**I still want to use all the built in features that Rails offers.

I was thinking maybe I should create the models to represent the data pulled from the web services, and populate them from the requested data.

Or

Maybe disable Rails active record when creating the app, and manually creating a single model for session.

---

### Other questions that don't belong here

*Assuming I won't need activerecord what are the best ways to handle sessions in Rails?*

*How often should I rely on JavaScript while building a Rails app?*

I really appreciate any help, and any Getting-Into-Rails advice is more than welcome.

Comment: It sounds like you're using Rails as just a front-end to display the API data then?  Is there any more context you can provide regarding what the Rails app is supposed to do?

Comment: Yes, I'll be using Rails as a front-end tool to build an app, I already have an API in place.
My question is quite general just an app that won't use a database directly, but will get all the information from an API. (i.e I would be able to log in, and add/retrieve entries), only I want this to happen via API communication rather than directly with a database.
And the reason for my question is to understand best practices/conventions.
Not sure if that explains my situation much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose to store your session data in a database using ActiveRecord but this is certainly not a requirement. By default, Rails uses Cookies to store session data. This is provided by [CookieStore](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html).

So when a user logs in to your Rails application, you can first authenticate their credentials with your API and on success, store their `user_id` (or token or whatever you're using to identify this user) in the session. On subsequent requests, you can use the value stored in the session to identify the user.

In terms of structuring your models to talk with your API, [ActiveResource](https://github.com/rails/activeresource) is a good option although you may find it a bit finicky depending on the API you're consuming. [Her](https://github.com/remiprev/her) is another alternative.

If the API you're using is a REST API that communicates via JSON, those libraries should work fine for you.

So to answer your questions...

1. You don't need to write to a database or use ActiveRecord to store session data. The Rails default is to use Cookies.
2. You can use as little or as much JavaScript within your Rails application as you like - this will largely depend on what you want the application to do.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks man.
So there isn't a "Rails amount" of javascript to use?

Comment: @MrHaze not at all. Rails includes jQuery, jQueryUI, and Turbolinks by default and you can build on top of this if you desire but that's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of reading, and asking Rails developers, I'm starting to form a solution to my issue.

apparently there is an existing Gem (surprise! surprise!) that enables an API consuming rails application, and maintains the structure of activerecord.

The Gem is called [activeresource](https://github.com/rails/activeresource), It's well documented, and as far as I can tell, it will do the job, and quite nicely at that.